# Merging a forked repo to the main repo

Tags: git

How do I merge code in a forked repository to the main repository(from where the fork was created) where I have push permission.
The main repository is forked for some development and now we need to get the changes to it merged in the main repository. And there is no pull request as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. fetch the latest changes from the main repository to the local with `git fetch`
2. merge them with with your changes with `git merge`
3. push the resulted commit with `git push`

steps 1 & 2 can be combined into a signle one with `git pull`